# How to replicate the merged cell values in a pivot table in Amazon QuickSight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

So I have a usecase with a excelsheet data to be replicated in QuickSight.

so the excelsheet data has been copied in the dataset in qicksight which looks like

```
ColA   ColB ColC
Arjun  1030 1200
       1200 1200
Sagar  1340 1300
       1450 1300
Tuhin  1560 1500
       1780 1500
```

I want the colC should be converted to a single value something like below.

```
ColA   ColB  ColC
Arjun  1030  
       1200  1200
Sagar  1340
       1450  1300
Tuhin  1560
       1780  1500
```

I am trying to get the denserank value using a calculated field but I could not find a function which will act similar to the above. Actually all the rows are getting filled.

any hints to resolve this issue will be highly appreciated.